# Recurrence Relation First Five Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Currently in my discrete math class we are working on Recurrence Relations and sequences. Now there are similar problems to mine on here but I could not find what I was looking for. My teacher for this class just plain cannot teach and was hoping someone could help explain this to me.

The problem I have is to find the first five terms of this sequence:
$a_n=3a_{n-1} - 1$; with $a_1 = 1$

Then I have to find an explicit or closed definition for this sequence? If anyone could please offer up some help it would truly be appreciated.

Comment: First step.  Figure out $a_2$.  Does the formula $a_n=3a_{n-1} - 1$ tell you anything about $a_2$?

Comment: You can plug the values in & calculate the first $5$ values ? Add this to your question. For an explicit formula ... Hint: it might involve powers of $3$.

Comment: My teacher did not explain this to us, she gave it to us to try and solve for some extra points. I simply cannot figure out how this works, I've read through my book here and it made it more confusing. From my understanding you have to plug in the value from a1 for a2?

Comment: Yes, $a_2 = 3\cdot a_1-1 = 3\cdot 1 - 1 = 2$.

Comment: so for a3 would be a3 = 3 * a2 - 1 = 3 * 2 - 1 = 5?

Comment: @hotrod28  Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Just want to clarify one more: a4 = 3 * a3 - 1 = 3 * 5 -  1 = 14

Comment: Also can someone explain the explicit formula for this? You guys have no idea how much help this I am grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_2=3a_1=(3^1)a_1-(3^0)$$
$$a_3=3(3a_1-1)-1=9a_1-4=(3^2)a_1-(3^0+3^1)$$
$$a_4=3(9a_1-4)-1=27a_1-13=(3^3)a_1-(3^0+3^1+3^2)$$
and so forth. Since $a_1=1$, we get

### $$a_n=3^{n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{3^k}$$

Inductive proof as requested:
$$a_1=1$$
$$a_n=3a_{n-1}-1 (A)$$
Show that $$a_n=3^{n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{3^k} (B)$$
Step $1$: Prove for $n=2$.
$$A\rightarrow a_2=3\cdot1-1=2$$
$$B\rightarrow a_2=3^1-\sum_{x=0}^{0}{3^x}=3^1-3^0=2$$
Hence proved true for $n=2$.

Inductive step: Assume true for $n=k$, then show for $n=k+1$

Via statement $A$ we are showing that $a_{k+1}=3a_k-1$
$$a_k=3^{k-1}-(3^0+...+3^{k-2})$$
$$a_{k+1}=3^{k}-(3^0+...+3^{k-1})$$
$$\frac{1}{3}a_{k+1}=3^{k-1}-(3^{-1}+...+3^{k-2})$$
$$\frac{1}{3}a_{k+1}=3^{k-1}-(3^0+...+3^{k-2})-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{1}{3}a_{k+1}=a_k-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$a_{k+1}=3a_k-1$$
Hence we have proved the statement true for $n=2$, and for $n=k+1$ when $n=k$ has been assumed, hence the statement is true for all $n \in \Bbb Z, n\ge 2$.

Comment: Is the bottom part of your answer the explicit formula?

Comment: Yes. Have you used sums before?

Comment: The answer I got is a1 = 1, a2 = 2,  a3 = 5, a4 = 14, a5 =41 is this the correct first 5 terms?

Comment: We are just starting sums now

Comment: Those are completely correct.

Comment: If $n=5$ the formula tells you $a_5=3^4-\sum_{k=0}^{3}{3^k}=81-(3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3)=81-(1+3+9+27)=81-40=41$

Comment: Awesome, I am starting to understand it now. I am a little confused on the formula part though but I appreciate your help. Is there a way to prove this by prove by induction as well?

Comment: I'll have a look at that now and add what I get to my answer.

Comment: Awesome I appreciate your help, I wish there was a way to compensate for your help.

Comment: Sorted. If any part doesn't make sense just let me know and I'll try to iron it out a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the first terms of the sequence as suggested in the comments you can also arrive at a closed expression. As example, from:

$$
a_4=3a_3-1=3(3a_2-1)-1=3(3(3a_1-1)-1)-1=3(3(3\cdot 1-1)-1)-1=3(3^2-3-1)-1=3^3-3^2-3^1-1
$$
it is suggested that, for $n>1$, we have:
$$
a_n=3^{n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}3^k
$$
and you can verify that this result satisfies the given recursive definition.

Comment: Thanks for your help the two of you are great! I think Rhys is helping me with a proof by induction but any ideas on that as well?